# How to restrict type/size of file uploads in any plugin?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, limit, uploads

I have a plugin, in this case it's Woocommerce Product Add-on which has an ability to allow folks to upload a file for the item being purchased. However, there is no restriction and I'm looking for a way to restrict.

Since all plugins are handled by Wordpress natively, how can I utilize the `wp_handle_upload(`) and `wp_max_upload_size()` fuctions to control/restrict file uploads? I would very much like some direction please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [upload_mimes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes) filter to restrict the image type as :

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','restict_image_type'); 

function restict_image_type($mimes) { 
    $mimes = array( 
                'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg', 
                'gif' => 'image/gif', 
                'png' => 'image/png', 
    ); 
    return $mimes;
}
```

For upload limit you can set in .htaccess one of the following;

```
LimitRequestBody 1048576 //( 1MB)
php_value upload_max_filesize 1M
php_value post_max_size 1M
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Silly question: I know that the function goes into the wp-includes/function.php, however where do I place the "add_filter" function to call up on it?

Comment: find the functions.php on your installed theme.

Comment: Ah, so I basically add the whole code block above into that file. Gotcha.

Comment: As for the LimitRequestBody function, wouldn't 1MB be 1048576 instead of 1073741824?

Comment: Oh yes mistake.. please rectify ..